# How do you monitor communications on a positive-grounded device from a negative-grounded desktop?

Tags: grounding, rs485, ground-loop

[image: Look at the ground wires connected to the POSITIVE terminal output.]I have a need to read the signals being sent between two boards in a lighting fixture.

In preparing to do this I have read much about the chips, RS485, and analysers/decoders that are out there. I am getting close to purchasing a USB to RS485 adapter and software to use it with - but have been unable to find critical information specific to my situation:

My desktop computer is negative grounded and the device is positive grounded.

I don't have a laptop that can be used for this purpose (which I have read could be used if it wasn't plugged into mains when connected to the fixture.)

Stuck with just the desktop to use, it seems to mean I'll just short it all out if I connect the grounds - possibly damaging the fixture, my desktop, the adapter, or any combo of these.

How do you properly set up for reading the signals with a -GND desktop and the +GND device?

Comment: There are isolated RS-485 to USB adapters. Out of curiosity on my end, is there a datasheet or manual for the positive ground device? I've never seen one before.

Comment: Your question is unclear and a schematic would help. Are you saying that these two devices are powered from the same power supply but that the device has its positive supply connect grounded? This seems most unlikely for anything more modern than an early transistor radio. You can add a schematic using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip.

Comment: @Transistor Um, sorry but how? The desktop is grounded internally like pretty much any desktop is - negative grounded, and the fixture is grounded to the positive DC output AND actual earth, positive grounded. They are two distinct items, and I'm going to connect them. What can I add to make it more clear?

Comment: So it runs on negative voltage?

Comment: @Toor - If it's as simple as that and I don't have to worry as long as I buy an isolated adapter, please post that as an answer!!! (And wow that's too cool if that IS all there is to it. I was worried I'd have to  make something or buy some other thing to put in the middle.)

Comment: @uglyoldbob - yes, sorta. See picture I just posted. Earth to circuit board grounds AND to positive DC output. Don't ask ME what that's all about, first time I've ever seen it.

Comment: @Toor - Regarding datasheets: Don't I WISH! Nothing out there that I can find, and trust me I have many hours into searching for the docs for this fixture.

Comment: The photo supports my point that it is most unlikely to have a positive earth. It seems to be a home-made device so I suspect that it should be earthed on the PSU negative. What is the device? Check if there is a voltage regulator on board. If so, it is almost certainly on the positive rail and if that's the case then the earthing is wrong.

Comment: @Transistor I have removed the components from the original housing, but they are mass-manufactured light fixtures, sold by the thousands. The GREEN WIRES are POSITIVE. The same green wires junction with all other grounds in the system, and all connect to earth on the mains supply line. I'm not making it up, man!

Comment: If I should add more photos of the fixture before I disassembled it, and more of it as I disassembled, it -  just say so. But the "on the table" wiring is exactly as it is in the fully assembled fixture, it is all just outside the box it came in.

Comment: Oh, and it is operational as it sits there on the table... So it's wired correctly, no mistakes made. I can send it DMX instructions and all functions as expected.

Comment: Ah, OK, it's lighting and it has a dimmer interface built in. It still seems very strange.

Comment: @Toor To see more about this thing check https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20665/likely-protocol-determination-by-chip-ids-and-connections where I have asked for help with figuring out the protocol between boards.

Comment: Those datasheets in your link...those are chips on the PCB? You listed two RS485 transceivers. One isolated and one not. If your board is positive grounded it would make sense that the designer built in the ability to use RS-485 without needing an isolated RS-485 transceiver since they would run into the same issue you are running into. They didn't use an expensive isolated RS-485 converter with built-in isolated power supply for no reason.

Comment: Furthermore, the fact they have a second non-isolated one elsewhere suggests it's safe to connect or isolated some other way. Your drawings indicate there are isolators right beside the unisolated RS-485 transceiver so it's possible they are isolating that transceiver as well, but only you can tell for sure via testing electrical connections. BTW RS-485 does not always need GND connected though it's good practice if your transceivers are not isolated. But in your case one definitely is and the second looks like it may be so you wouldn't connect grounds when using the RS485 if they are.

Comment: All the RS485 chips are grounded on their designated ground pin (there is continuity from chip ground pins to earth). That one chip on the I.R. board is also grounded on its RE pin. How do we move this to PM? I can't see a way to PM you here. We are WAY off topic now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are isolated USB-RS-485 converters you can buy. They allow data flow while keeping the grounds (indeed, all signals) on both sides galvanically isolatd from each other. They have their limits to how much isolation they can provide between both ends though (usually limited to ONLY a few hundred or thousands of volts).

If the adapter requires a power input on both sides, ensure that the respective power supplies used are also isolated (like a wall-wart with a transformer inside and the like), especially on the end your your device is on or else you'll run into the same issue as before.

Comment: As written, it reads like a comment. Please rephrase and add more info to clarify that this fully addresses the issue? Future readers would appreciate reading WHY it is that simple to address the problem of differing grounds, I'd think. We noobs appreciate it whenever answerers get verbose!

Comment: As requested...